# Performance impact of having Polymorphic collections in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, wiredtiger

Say one document(Level 1) is supposed to have `N(k)` different kinds of items as sub-document arrays(Level 2), and these are stored in a separate collection(s?) due to lack of query optimisation for deep nested array sub docs. 
Now, we are supposed to fetch `N(d1)` level-1 docs, each has `N(d2)` number of sub docs (total count of level-2 docs for one level-1 doc is `N(d2)`)

What are the pros and cons of having all those item kinds in a single collection vs a collection of each type. Taking into consideration the following points:

- The storage engine used is WT

  - DB can read while other documents are being written to same collection. [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/).
  - The read-write lock is document level and not collection level as with previous cases. [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/).
- Sparse Indexing is allowed, since the fields can differ from type to type
- The deployment type is a sharded cluster
- All query-able fields are indexed (not blindly though) => `$or` operator can use indexes
- A point in favour of one approach automatically means it leads to degradation of performance in other approach.

How the query will work in case of Polymorphic collection:

- All different types can be fetched in a single query(using `$or`) operation and then attached to their parent documents in the server app. We can also use aggregate `$group` to group one type of docs together. Thus,

  - decreasing the network induced query latency.
  - decreasing the number of connections the from the server.
- Since, the sub-docs are attached back to their parent docs, it requires a for loop on the server side. Which has to loop over `N(d1)` docs at minimum - in case aggregation `$group` is used at query level - or  `N(d1) * N(d2)` times if the sub-docs are not already grouped.

How the query will work in case each type has its own collection:

- `N(k)` queries are made, as soon as a query returns we can attach the sub-doc to its parent doc.
- We can, again, use aggregation `$group` and thereby limiting the server side loop to `N(d1)` iterations

In favour of a single collection:

- Less number of connections used. ( consistent at 1 per query )
- consistent latency. ( as an implication of earlier point )
- ?

In favour of multiple:

- An organisation structure we are more used to. ( subjective )
- ?

How else could each case effect performance?